# Capture playing sound

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-audio, macos-carbon

I would like to build a program that can catch sound played on Mac OS X, either all sound or from individual programs. Is that possible? I've been reading a lot of documentation but have not found much that looks useful. It could be that I'm just looking in the wrong direction. Can it be done and are there a specific group of APIs that I should focus on?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but the idea would be to direct all sound output to an audio "device" (a kernel component) that allows it to be captured. According to [this page](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Recording_audio_playing_on_the_computer), you can do that with [soundflower](http://cycling74.com/soundflower-landing-page/).

If you want to do it programmatically, I'd install the soundflower driver and look into controlling it from your program.